# How do I get different keys for same list but different elements in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am starting with React (5 days ago) so sorry If this is a basic question or I perhaps I am not formulating this properly.

I have a JSON that contains this format.

```
[{
    "id":"1",
    "header": "Ultimo Momento",
    "titulo": "Alerta Mundial",
    "texto": "Aliens nos atacan sin piedad.",
    "tipo": "Info",
    "loc": "left"
},
{
    "id":"2",
    "header": "Info",
    "titulo": "Vuelve el Futbol",
    "texto": "Aliens nos atacan sin piedad.",
    "tipo": "Light",
    "loc": "left"
},
{
    "id":"3",
    "header": "Info",
    "titulo": "Alerta Mundial",
    "texto": "Aliens nos atacan sin piedad.",
    "tipo": "Dark",
    "loc": "right"
}]
```

I have a Component called **Noticias** that will render in two different columns and will show only the ones that are correct for that column (loc: right for column on the right, and left for left)

```
    <MDBCol md="3" className="d-flex align-items-center flex-column">
      <Noticias Noticias={NoticiasData} Location={"left"} />
    </MDBCol >


    <MDBCol  md="6" className="d-flex align-items-center flex-column">
      <Salas Salas={SalasData} />
    </MDBCol >


    <MDBCol  md="3" className="d-flex align-items-center flex-column">
      <Noticias Noticias={NoticiasData} Location={"right"} />
    </MDBCol >

  </MDBRow>
```

The problem I have is that I get duplicate keys because is the same component and the same logic.

```
class Noticias extends Component {
state = {}

render() {
    const {

        Noticias,
        Location

    } = this.props;


    return (
        Noticias.filter((noticia) => noticia.loc === Location).map((noticia, idx) =>
            (
                noticiaGenerator(noticia, idx)
            ))
    )
}
```

}

And noticiaGenerator looks like this:

```
const noticiaGenerator = (noticia, key) =>
<>
    <Card
        bg={noticia.tipo.toLowerCase()}
        key={key}
        id={noticia.id}
        text={noticia.tipo.toLowerCase() === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'white'}
        style={{ width: '18rem' }}
    >
        <Card.Header>{noticia.header}</Card.Header>
        <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>{noticia.titulo}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>{noticia.texto}</Card.Text>
        </Card.Body>
    </Card>
    <br />
</>
```

The error:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Is this considered bad? These are my first hours of flight here.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't show and reproducible example, where is the problem? How `noticiaGenerator` looks like?

Comment: @DennisVash thank you for pointing that out. I added the piece of code missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give a `key` prop to the **container**, also you already have a unique id `noticia.id` so you should use it:

```
const noticiaGenerator = (noticia) => (
  <div key={noticia.id}>
    <Card>
      ...
    </Card>
    <br />
  </div>
);
```

Read more [about why keys are necessary](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys) .

It says:

> **When children have keys**, React uses the key to match children in the original tree with children in the subsequent tree.

And in your example:

```
const noticiaGenerator = (noticia, key) => (
  // v this is the child that  should have the key.
  <React.Fragment>
    // v useless key
    <Card key={key}></Card>
    <br />
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much. Error removed. I will consider the concept of KEY to the container. I will read more in the link provided. Thank you.